# iOS in-app purchase metadata

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am about to create my first iOS app with in-app purchase. I read documentation and everything, but I can't find anywhere how to append some metadata to in-app purchase object. I would like to add some additional information to each item, like category, sub-title e.t.c.

iBooks uses this for category, author and other stuff, so it should be possible. I presume they are using in-app purchase in iBooks, is that correct?

Only solution I came up with so far is to have all metadata on my server and retrieve them when items from store load. Is there any other way?

I need to add new items (and possibly new metadata) after app is online, so I can't put them inside app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. That's what you're *supposed* to do. Metadata and the like is entirely up to you, and Apple provides no inbuilt mechanism in StoreKit or iTunes Connect for supplying it.

Comment: that sucks :( maybe I could use Description field so store any additional data and then parse it. 255 character could be enough. Or is this visible somewhere outside app (like in itunes or something)

Comment: It's visible in iTunes. It's also used by Apple when evaluating your IAP products. Are you unable to provide any HTTP-based support in your app? Surely you can hit up your app's website for product descriptions.

Comment: I can, I just wanted to simplify it as much as possible, but looks like I will have to do it complicated way :)